# RDP Access on Whonix

Tags: tor, remote-desktop, virtualbox

I'm trying to access to access to my RDP on Whonix (over Tor and despite all dangers) this way

> rdesktop myip

but I'm always getting error

> Autoselecting keyboard map 'en-us' from locale Core(error):
> tcp_recv(), recv() failed: Connection reset by peer

How can this be done?